# How I can detect window resize instantly in angular 2?

Tags: events, angular

Some features in my component turn on or off depend on browser size, therefore I want to check browser width on resize event. However, I could do it using OnInit method. But I need to refresh browser when resize happened to update browser width

```
 ngOnInit() {
     if (window.innerWidth <= 767){
       ---- do something
      }
   }
```

I tried to use OnChanges method, but it does not work either.

```
OnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
console.log( 'width:====>' + changes[window.innerWidth].currentValue);
  if ( changes[window.innerWidth].currentValue <= 767 ){
      ---- do something
}
```

}

is there any suggestions or alternative way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could just put handler on `resize` event over `window` object, but this will allow you to put only single `resize` event, latest registered event on `onresize` will work.

```
constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) {
    window.onresize = (e) =>
    {
        //ngZone.run will help to run change detection
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            console.log("Width: " + window.innerWidth);
            console.log("Height: " + window.innerHeight);
        });
    };
}
```

To make it more angular way use `@HostListener('window:resize')` inside your component, which will allow to call your resize function(on which `HostListner` decorator has been mount) on `resize` of window.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event){
   console.log("Width: " + event.target.innerWidth);
}
```

Comment: This works on one component, but it doesn't work when I add it to another component. I suppose because the onresize event has already been defined.

Comment: `onresize` event can be registered on a window only once, if you try to register `onresize` event then the older will get discarded..

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying. I went with the Host Listener solution, it allowed for multiple resize events (one in each component), and seems a 'more angular way' to do things,

Comment: @Sam you're correct, parden me. I updated an answer with more explanation. I should have updated this before. Thanks for heads up mate :)

Comment: i have angular app inside an iframe of a php web app. How do i make it work of the resize of the parent window.

Answer (score 22):

Use HostListener. You should probably debounce the resize event though before doing anything, it will fire everytime the size changes which could be dozens or hundreds of times in a few milliseconds as the user drags the window size.

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
class TestComponent {
    @HostListener('window:resize')
    onWindowResize() {
        //debounce resize, wait for resize to finish before doing stuff
        if (this.resizeTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(this.resizeTimeout);
        }
        this.resizeTimeout = setTimeout((() => {
            console.log('Resize complete');
        }).bind(this), 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works awesome, thanks so much! Works in angular 5.

Comment: Works great! Angular 6

Answer (score 8):

An easier way would be using the resize method on the html block that you want to detect:

```
<div class="some-class" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">...</div>
```

Then in your `.ts` file you can just add:

```
onResize(event) {

   const innerWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
   console.log(innerWidth);

   if (innerWidth <= 767) {
      ...do something
   }
}
```

Add this **outside** of the `ngOnInit() {}` unless you wanted the window size on page load.

When you resize your window, you'll see the `console.log`

Comment: that's a very neat solution

Comment: This works for resizing the window, but not when the browser tab is dragged from one window to another of a different size. Is there a different `window:` to call for this? EDIT: Also, it doesn't change the size if you are double clicking the title bar to make it go full screen...